# Camera SurfaceView is crashing after starting it several times

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am developing a game that has two activities which are camera surfaceView and a fire button in addition to the weapon as imageView.The two activities have same code.After switching between the activities several times the app crashes. This is my code and below it the stack trace:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,OnClickListener {

Camera mCamera;
SurfaceView mPreview;
Button shoot;
TextView rounds;
int shootsound;
int reloadsound;
int music;

SoundPool spool;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    new TapContextSDK(getApplicationContext()).initialize();  
    new TapContextSDK(getApplicationContext()).showAd();   
    mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mCamera = Camera.open();
    shoot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    shoot.setOnClickListener(this);
    rounds=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);



    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    shootsound= spool.load(this, R.raw.shoot, 2);
    reloadsound= spool.load(this, R.raw.reload, 2);
    music= spool.load(this, R.raw.music, 2);

    new TapContextSDK(getApplicationContext()).initialize();  
    new TapContextSDK(getApplicationContext()).showAd(); 


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCamera.release();

}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {       
    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(4); //480h x 720w

    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {                        
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("PREVIEW","surfaceDestroyed");
}

public void shoot(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool.play(shootsound, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

public void reload(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool.play(reloadsound, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

public void music(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool.play(music, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

public void vibrateMe() {


    Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    vibrate.vibrate(100);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(arg0.getId()) {


    case R.id.button1:

        int tmp = Integer.valueOf( rounds.getText().toString());

        if(tmp==0)
        {
            rounds.setText("12");
            reload();
        }
        else
        {
            shoot();
            vibrateMe();
            rounds.setText( String.valueOf( tmp-1) );
        }



      break;

}
     }}
```

Stack Trace:

```
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jouni.camsniper/com.jouni.camsniper.Machinegun}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera servicef
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:307)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:283)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at com.jouni.camsniper.Machinegun.onCreate(Machinegun.java:52)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
07-11 17:42:15.241: E/AndroidRuntime(28651):    ... 11 more
07-11 17:42:18.924: D/Process(28651): killProcess, pid=28651
```

Any suggestion how to make the app more stable (No Crashes) ??

Comment: I would strongly consider not using two activities in this case. Use one activity, changing that activity's UI, instead of launching a separate activity. In particular, your objective would be to keep the camera preview going, rather than frequently opening and closing the camera.

Comment: I have a sniper,gun,pistol..... in weapons activity

You mean I should change the activity layout when different weapon is selected ?